# Unknown prop 'theme' on <input> tag: React-Select v2

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-select

I have an issue with [React-Select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select). Just started using it as it fits my business requirements.

```
return (
  <FormGroup row>
    <Col md={6}>
      <Select
        placeholder="Please Select..."
        name={fieldName}
        onChange={onChange}
        options={options} />
    </Col>
  </FormGroup>
)
```

I did not show the rest of the code; `fieldName`, `onChange` & `options` are props passed from parent-component to child-component.

On the browser, the `Dropdown` bar seems to be working but I am still getting a warning:

> Warning: Unknown prop 'theme' on `<input>` tag. Remove this prop from the
>   element. in input (created by AutosizeInput) in div (created by
>   AutosizeInput) [...]

I have a couple of questions:

1. There is no theme props I am passing.
2. What `<input>` tag are they talking about?
3. Is this a known issue with React-Select V2?

Thanks community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue that was opened for this [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3112), and apparently solved in v2.1.1.

Issue is in [this](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/90282815caafcafd73b196b57144132f00ca36a6/src/components/Input.js) component.

Comment: I am using version 2.0.0

Comment: @AKJ update it to version 2.1.1 to remove the warning.

Comment: I am unable to get version 2.1.1 in my company's environment. If the warning isnt detrimental to any performance, I will ignore it. Or is it something i should be concerned about?

Comment: @AKJ I doubt you should be concerned about this warning (it's a warning, not an error), but as soon as you can, upgrade. I updated as soon as I knew about this so I cannot tell with certainty.